# How can i skip the last response which has been requested first?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Each request uses the below code;

```
const source = this.httpClient.get<any>('http://api.example.com', { params: params, 
responseType : 'json' }, ).subscribe();

source.pipe(
    //How can i skip the last response which has been requested first?
)
```

I want to skip B' response using rxjs.

[image: Discription Image]

Comment: You have `subscribe()` at the end of `this.httpClient...subscribe()` which returns a `Subscription` and not an Observable.

Comment: Then, how to skip B' response using Observable. I don't know how to achieve this. @martin, and Subscription can't do this?

Comment: You can use `skip(1)`, `skipLast(1)` or `ignoreElements()` depending on what you want to achieve

Comment: `skip(1)`, `skipLast(1)` just skip whatever `Observable` return i want to skip exactly `B'` which is late response than `A'`

Comment: Then use `filter`. I think I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry, but I want to build search feature which has 'Auto Complete' like amazon using rxjs, switchMap is quite decent method for my requirement but,
When I type fastly for 2~3 second, then Auto Complete feature does not work for those times @martin

Comment: @RayKim I don't understand how you manage to get a stream using httpClient. `httpClient.get` emits only once. If you have a source that emits elements, check my response using `filter` operator

Comment: Ok, I think `httpClient.get` emits only once is the point.. then how to make Observable to sequently? @madjaoue

Comment: @RayKim so If I understand, each time you request `this.httpClient.get<any>('http://api.example.com', { params: params, responseType : 'json' }, )` you get a different response ? 
In this case, I can provide you with code that will request the server each x seconds, for n times. Would that be acceptable ?

Comment: Yes I get different response. Which mean, 
B' response is quite heavy so response could be late.
A' response is quite light so response could be faster than B'.
SO, Eventhough request of B requested faster than A, B' response is could be late than A'.
I get unwanted response. I expected response A'. because, The time of Request A is faster than B.

If two request is responding ( on processing ) 
I want to ignore last response if that request of the last response time is faster first request

Or, i just want make `Observerble` to sequently. If it is possible @madjaoue

Comment: @RayKim Check my edited answer, I put a detailed explanation of 2 solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you make two requests, made to the same endpoint `https://api.example.com/endpoint`: `RequestA` and `RequestB`.

Let's also call the responses `ResponseA` and `ResponseB`.

There are two possible solutions I can think of.

*Case 1 :* ResponseA and ResponseB can be differentiated by looking at their content.

*Case 2 :* The stream is not structured, you can't infer which response is it just by looking at the content.

## Case 1 : You can discriminate the content

The stream looks like `{'name': 'B', ...} -> {'name': 'A', ...} -> {'name' : 'B', ...}`.
Then the best fit is  [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) operator:

```
// example of a stream
const source = this.httpClient.get<any>('http://api.example.com',
                                   {params: params, responseType: 'json'})

interval(2000) // could be replace by `fromEvent('someEvent')` for example
.pipe(
  take(10), // take only 10 first responses
  mergeMap(source),
  filter(element => element['name'] != 'B')
)
.subscribe(element=> console.log('Received name :', element['name'])
```

*Output*:

> "Received name : {'name': 'A'}"

## Case 2 : Keep the fastest response

Discrimination by speed :

```
// example of a stream
const source1 = this.httpClient.get<any>('http://api.example.com',
                                   {params: params, responseType: 'json'})
const source2 = this.httpClient.get<any>('http://api.example.com',
                                   {params: params, responseType: 'json'})

source1
.pipe(
  merge(source2),
  take(1)
)
.subscribe(resp=> console.log('fastest response :', resp)
```

Comment: I really appreciate with concrete answer
But As I said before, I am building my own search feature called 'Auto Complete' like amazon, 
in case2 , then, do I create each source per typing?
When I type `hello`, the request returns 100 obects like 'hello world', 'hello sweetie'..etc. called response B'.
When I type `hello world`, the request returns 1 object just 'hello world' called response A'.
Although I typed `hello world` ( it contains response B', A' as I explained above ), what I receive  response eventually is `hello` because `hello` response is heavy

Comment: When I type `Hello`. FYI, I must create source1, source2, source3, source4, source5.
From a optimization point of view, I don't think it was the solution I expected. 
I know my explanation was very insufficient, but my requirement is not. But if you want. I will accept this answer. Because this is quite decent answer, although my question was insufficient

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure if I understand your question but I think you can use [switchMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) to cancel the previous emission.

Make sure to NOT return subscription! like what you are doing in you example!

What you can do is:

```
this.httpClient.get<any>(URL).pipe(
  swtichMap(data => data)
).subscribe(data => data) <= here you will get B
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want to skip previous emission.
I want to build search feature which has 'Auto Complete' like amazon using rxjs,
When I type fastly for 2~3 second, then Auto Complete feature does not work for those times

Comment: so you might need `debounceTime(NumberInMs)` to not trigger the observable every time you type something in the search input.